# Defining Markers in the buffer with corresponding offsets

Tags: assembly, asmx, mips

I think my code is right but I am having errors. Can the code be modified correctly and can it be written in much better form?

```
.text
main:
lui $a0, 2
li $v0, 1
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that your are trying to load a register with the address of a (displaced) label.
Instead of using pseudoinstruction `li` you should use pseudoinstruction `la`.

E.g:

```
  la $t0, offset($v0) 
  la $t1, marker($v0) 
  add $v0, $v0, 1
  la $t2, offset($v0) 
  la $t3, market($v0)
```

Comment: That makes much more sense. Could you also please see if the rest of the code is correct and can it be coded better?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do so I cannot tell if there is a better way to code it. Anyways I don't see anything blatantly wrong.